# Refreshing a view controller.m

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a form with random questionnaire pulled from a web server. I need to have a button executing (setNeedsDisplay) to refresh the page... The app crashed when i clicked the button with error:

*Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ExercisesViewController setNeedsDisplay]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a1e840'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x13f3022 0x1584cd6 0x13f4cbd 0x1359ed0 0x1359cb2 0x963054 0x974fc6 0x57c0 0x13f4e99 0x4014e 0x400e6 0xe6ade 0xe6fa7 0xe6266 0x301a1a 0x13c799e 0x135e640 0x132a4c6 0x1329d84 0x1329c9b 0x12dc7d8 0x12dc88a 0x3d626 0x1f96 0x1f05)
terminate called throwing an exception*

```
//Add refreshing agenda
    scrollViewFrame = CGRectMake(0, 200, 80, 40);
    mark = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    mark.frame = scrollViewFrame;
    [mark setTitle:@"Get Score" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [mark setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    [mark addTarget:self 
             action:@selector(markButtonSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [scrollView addSubview:mark];
```

...

```
- (IBAction)markButtonSelected:(id)sender{
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(setNeedsDisplay) withObject:nil];
```

}

Is this a syntax issue? I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742099/refreshing-a-view) that it is something to do with thread. Can someone explain about thread or is there a more direct approach?
Thanx in advance...

Answer (score 4):

`setNeedsDisplay` method is `UIView`'s method, not `UIViewController`. In your `markButtonSelected:` method just add: `[self.view setNeedsDisplay];`

Comment: Well the good news is it doesn't crash but the view isn't refreshed.

Comment: What setNeedsDisplay method does, is marking this view for redraw in the next event lifecycle, which causes the drawRect: method of an UIView to be called, the view gets redrawn and its layer gets cached in the GPU. So if the view you're calling setNeedsDisplay on is not a subclassed view with implemented drawRect: method, then setNeedsDisplay does not fit your needs and you need another approach to complete your task. Unfortunately we can't help you, if you don't show some more code.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
```

Comment: You shouldn't be doing things with UIViews in a background thread

Comment: true. Good point. I was focusing on the call to setNeedsDisplay on the view vs. controller.

Answer (score 0):

view updates should be done on main thread.

use

```
[self.view performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setNeedsDisplay) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

Comment: setNeedsDisplay only updates a dirty flag so the view is rendered on the next draw, you do not need waitUntilDone:YES.

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke setNeedsDisplay on the UIView, not the UIViewController. Doing this asynchronously yields better performance. Using GCD to do asynchronous work is the Apple's preferred way.

ie:

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
    });
```

Comment: My questionnaire is on a view controller itself not UIView. How do i implement that? in IBAction?

Comment: In your error message, the receiver is a UIViewController - thats where you error lies. A UIViewController has a member called 'view' that you can access.